# Connect to Elasticsearch server using R

Tags: r, elasticsearch

I am quite familiar with using Python to connect with Elasticsearch server, but as I am exploring the R language, I am stuck at this connecting part. I usually use this kind of code to connect with the server in Python:

```
    import requests
    import json
    RM_URL = "http://es-int-client-1.senvpc:9200/rm_201609/_search?timeout=10000"        
    payload = { 

                  "size": 10000000,
                  "query": {
                  "filtered": {  
                    "filter" : {
                      "bool": {
                        "must": [
                          {"term": {"events.id": str(event_id)}},
                          {"range": {"score_content_0": {"gte": score}} },
                          {"range": {"published_at": { "gte": str(start_date+"T00:00:00"), 
                                                    "lte": str(end_date+"T23:59:59")}}},
                          {"term": {"lang": la}}

                        ]
                      }
                     }
                    }
                    }  
                }

     r = requests.post(RM_URL, json=payload)
     results = json.loads(r.content, encoding='utf-8')
```

I would be glad if anyone could show me how to do the same in R, thanks!

Comment: There are 3 community-contributed R clients for Elasticsearch. You can check them out here and see some examples: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/community/current/index.html#r

Comment: thanks @Val I will check it out!

Comment: maintainer of `elastic` - encourage you to try `elastic` - let me know if  you have any questions. it supports passing in JSON payloads that you're familiar with